# Unable to run http command in Windows even after instaling

Tags: http, httpie

I ran the command 'pip install -U httpie' and it went fine:

[Windows Command Prompt saying "Requirement already satisfied: PySocks!=1.5.7,>=1.5.6 in c:\users'NAME'\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from requests[socks]>=2.22.0->httpie) (1.7.1)"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfSfP.png)
(click to view image)

But when I try to use the http command in Windows command prompt, it is unable to find the command.

[Windows Command Prompt saying "
http GET http://www.example.com
'http' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."](https://i.stack.imgur.com/orc9F.png)
(click to view image)

('http' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.)

Answer (score 1):

**It is for Windows:**

- All operations must be performed with administrator rights
- You need install Python.
- If python is installed, then update it

```bash
python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

- Install httpie

```bash
pip install -U httpie

http --version
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be due to the path that `pip` installs applications might not be in your `PATH`. Here is a possible [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-so-it-finds-my-modules-packages) for this problem.

---

Please also note that, HTTPie recommends usage of `chocolatey` for Windows based installations:

```
$ choco install httpie
```

Also please take a look at the documentation for [Installation Methods on Windows](https://httpie.io/docs/cli/chocolatey).